# Time Series Analysis in R : Frequency value in ts() function vs lag in acf plot

Tags: r, time-series

I am a newbie in time series analysis. I am having monthly sales data for 60 months, from January-2009 to December-20013, and trying to forecast sales for upcoming 6 months via ARIMA model. I read the data and convert it into time series object as follow :

```
 data <- read.csv(file="monthlySalesData.csv", header=TRUE)
 dataInTimeSeris <- ts(data, frequency = 12, start=c(2009,1), end=c(2013,12))
```

When I try to draw acf() plot to determine the lag after which my auto-correlation is dying down to zero, then I get scale of lag on X-axis in decimals. I am not having enough privilege to post image, but lag values on X-axis are in decimal with max lag as 1.5 . The acf values with plot=FALSE also come strange (It does not show lag for which it has calculated auto-correlation). I am not able to interpret this, and not able to find number of lags after which auto-correlation is dying down to zero.

```
 acf(dataInTimeSeries, plot=FALSE)

Autocorrelations of series ‘dataInTimeSeries’, by lag

0.0000 0.0833 0.1667 0.2500 0.3333 0.4167 0.5000 0.5833 0.6667 0.7500 0.8333 
 1.000  0.642  0.588  0.490  0.401  0.320  0.311  0.269  0.178  0.198  0.229 
0.9167 1.0000 1.0833 1.1667 1.2500 1.3333 1.4167 
 0.271  0.358  0.240  0.210  0.092  0.135  0.098
```

What is the issue - is there any problem with R settings, or data import or ts() function? And if this is how acf plots shows for monthly data, how to interpret it ?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can specify the maximum lag in the `acf` by setting the parameter `lag.max = 10`, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decimals you see are just years, e.g. 0.0833 = 1/12 year, 0.1667 = 2/12 year aso.

To get the ACF plot with lags as months you can try something like:

```
## Lacking reproducible example, I use simulated monthly data 
tt <- ts(arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=0.4),60), start=2001, deltat=1/12)
## Calculate, but not plot, acf
acfpl <- acf(tt, plot=FALSE)
## Transform the lags from years to months
acfpl$lag <- acfpl$lag * 12

## Plot the acf 
plot(acfpl, xlab="Lag (months)")
```

[image]

---

As I understand your problem you are dealing with is identifying the orders of ARMA. To do that you need both the ACF and PACF plots. When you say "dying to zero" you should not expect the values to be equal to zero after some lag. Values inside the 95% confidence interval (dashed blue lines) are not statistically significant (check also the notes in `?plot.acf`).

Identifying the order of an ARIMA model can be tricky, but there are some rules you can follow. E.g. processes AR(p) models have ACF like a damped exponential/sine function and PACF having p significant lags. E.g. MA(q) processes are the other way round.

Just to how it looks like for these two simple cases, I use `arima.sim` to simulate two time series, ARIMA(1,0,0) and ARIMA(0,0,1).

```
set.seed(1234)
arima100 <- arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=0.9), n=500)
arima001 <- arima.sim(list(order=c(0,0,1), ma=0.9), n=500)

par(mfrow=c(2,2), bycol=TRUE)
acf(arima100); acf(arima001)
pacf(arima100); pacf(arima001)
```

This produces the following plot:

[image]

ARIMA(1,0,0): ACF decays towards zero, and PACF has one significant lag.
ARIMA(0,0,1): ACF has one significant lag (after lag-0 which is always 1), and PACF appears like a damped sine function.

Now, just by looking at your ACF, I would dare say two things:

- Your process has probably an AR term (have to check PACF too)
- There may be seasonality in your data because of the spike at the 12th lag, i.e. one year (you can check that by looking at a plot of your data)

Some steps you can follow:

- Take differences if a trend is apparent in your data
- Take differences of lag 12 if you have yearly seasonality
- Plot ACF and PACF of your undifferenced and differenced data
- Fit models `arima` and check the residuals
- If you have several candidate models compare their AIC or BIC values.

Also reading a good book (I used Time Series Analysis by Henrik Madsen) or lecture notes ([these look good](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/)) can help you a lot.

Comment: Thanks Alko989 for the explanation!! It is quite useful for determining order of ARMA model. 

By "dying to zero", I mean auto-correlation becomes non-significant. My problem is specific to monthly data. If you look at the scale of lag in your acf and pacf plot , then it shows 5, 10, 15.......But for monthly data, the scale of lag comes as 0.2, 0.4, 0.6.....1.4. This makes difficult to find the lag value after which my auto-correlation becomes statistically insignificant. 

beginneR, I tried many combinations of lag.max. It does not help.  

Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer. Just as a tip: it is always helpful if you have a reproducible example in your questions.

Answer (score -1):

Using `coredata()` would do the trick too:

```
acf(coredata(dataInTimeSeries))
```