# decimal lag values in ACF plot instead of integers lags

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have a monthly time series. When I run the code acf(timeseries), the lags on the x axis show up as decimals instead of integers, as shown in the screenshot:
[image]

What is wrong? How could I have lags=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,etc) on the x-axis? I need something like this (photoshopped photo) (excuse the mis-alignment of values with ticks on the x-axis):

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982656/time-series-analysis-in-r-frequency-value-in-ts-function-vs-lag-in-acf-plot

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's because you are using a non-desirable format for the acf/ccf function.

I faced the same problem and I solved it by changing the input vectors from time-series (ts) to numeric:

[variable]<-as.numeric([variable])

And it worked. I hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a `tseries` object, you need to pass `coredata()` to the ACF and PACF functions:

```
acf(coredata(your_ts_object))
pacf(coredata(your_ts_object))
```

This will pass just the numerical values in the time series and won't make a mess, giving you integer lags.

Answer (score 0):

Try Acf (first letter is in upper-case) function in package "forecast".

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to get the results from the acf() function then plot it in your own like this:

**storing acf results:**

```
a=acf(ts,plot = F)  #ts is an annual time series(frequency =12)
```

**plotting acf:**

```
plot(a$lag*12,a$acf,xlab="Lag",ylab="ACF",main="",type="h")
```

note that you have to multiple the lag * frequency of your serie in this case 12.

**plotting horizontal lines:**

```
abline(h=c(-0.19,0,0.19),col=c("blue","black","blue"),lty=c(2,1,2))
```

- *h :* to specify where to plot ths lines
- *col :* for the colors of the lines
- *lty :* to specify the type of the line

that worked for me, i hope that's what you locking for

Answer (score 0):

As the ts is monthly, so the yearly lag is divided into 12. The first figure is just a portion of the total ACF (i.e., for 1.5 years approx.). To have ACF for the full ts, use `acf(ts_object, lag.max = the max length of your ts_object)`. E.g., if you have 15 years monthly data, then set `lag.max = 12*15`.